# How can check if the matrix of vectors and their corresponding labels match in sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scikit-learn

I want to train a model by using sklearn. As input I have a **list of lists** and a **list of labels**. They are constructed as follows:

```
for searchDay, features in listOfVecs.iteritems():
   vectors = []
   labels = []
   for feature in features:
       vectors.append(feature[0])
       labels.append(feature[1])
```

---

The vectors and their corresponding labels were in a dictionary. they mapped to each other. So we have a vector of vector as shown in `vectors.append(feature[0])` and a list of labels `labels.append(feature[1])`. `feature[0]` is a list and `feature[1]` is an integer label.

In order to use them as input in a model we have to do the following:

```
  matrix = np.array(vectors)           
  model = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor()
  model.fit(matrix, labels)
```

---

We first transform the vector into a numpy 2D array then we use the label in the `fit` function.

---

## Questions

1. Is what I am doing correct?
2. How can I know that for each corresponding row in the numpy 2D array we have the right label?

Comment: It could be more helpful if you upload your data. It seems okay. For the 2nd question, you can print the matrix and the labels and see if the correspondance is right .or ever use shape function for the numpy array to see the number of lines

Comment: a cleaner ( and maybe even faster way for long loops ) is to let `pandas` do the heavy lifting with it's DataFrames.  You could also get a good view of your data and a nice interface for working with them.  and with the  DataFrame.values you get the corresponding numpy array. See <http://pandas.pydata.org/>